# How to do one to many relation with MongoDB in ASP.NET core web API

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, mongodb-query

I want to get all the tweets done by that user using Username.

```
public class Tweet
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string TweetText { get; set; }
    public DateTime TweetTime { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public class UserRegistration
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Could you help me with the query in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: From the official documentation, you can change the string username to List<UserRegistrations> Users

Documentation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/dotnet/fundamentals/relationships/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start by following this article:

https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/csharp/using-linq-query-mongodb-dotnet-core-application/

It explains how to setup the connection to MongoDb and how to use LINQ to query MongoDB in .NET Core applications.

Let me know if there´s anything that is unclear in the article.